# Python: Splitting a path string containing double quotes

Tags: python

I am using a file containing brackets in Windows, which requires quotes in external processes.

I am trying to manipulate the location, but as the string is being passed with the quotes, when I use os.path.split, the double quotes are also being split.  Is there a better way to do this so that I don't need to do checks on the input string and strip and/or replace the double quotes?  I will be joining the filename to a new path that doesn't have double quotes.

```
fileWithPath = r'"C:\TEMP\my(file).txt"'
... do some stuff ...
sourcepath, filename = os.path.split(fileWithPath)
```

sourcepath has value: '"C:\TEMP'

filename has value: 'my(file).txt"'

Comment: What's wrong with strip?  You're already going to 'do some stuff' anyway.  `>>> fileWithPath.strip('"')`

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, I am relatively new to Python and am looking to find the best way forward.

Comment: `.strip` is easily the best way. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is to nuke the double-quotes that windows gives you:

```
firsWithPath = fileWithPath.replace('"', '')
```

But if you want to preserve some quotes and nuke only one ones on the ends, then you're better off with:

```
firsWithPath = fileWithPath.strip('"')
```

After either of these operations, splitting on `'\\'` should work just fine

**EDIT**:

As @jdi mentions in the comments, you really should split on `os.path.sep` instead of `'\\'` for portability

Comment: I would recommend sticking with `os.path.split` instead of a string split  on "\\". It is more portable. Windows paths support "/" in python.